# Why is the output saying null when I try to output the closest time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

The output is:

Testing first bus time: 2000-01-01 11:40:00 +0000

Closest time: (null)

Why is the first bus time in my array saying it is 11:40 when I set it as 6:40? And why at the end is it saying null? Thank you.

```
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        formatter.dateFormat = @"H:mm:ss";

        NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T1 = [formatter dateFromString:@"06:40:00"]; // 6:40 AM
        NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T2 = [formatter dateFromString:@"07:50:00"]; // 7:50 AM
        NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T3 = [formatter dateFromString:@"08:20:00"]; // 8:20 AM
        NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T4 = [formatter dateFromString:@"08:50:00"]; // 8:50 AM
        NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T5 = [formatter dateFromString:@"09:20:00"]; // 9:20 AM
        NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T6 = [formatter dateFromString:@"09:50:00"]; // 9:50 AM
        NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T7 = [formatter dateFromString:@"10:20:00"]; // 10:20 AM
        NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T8 = [formatter dateFromString:@"10:50:00"]; // 10:50 AM
        NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T9 = [formatter dateFromString:@"11:20:00"]; // 11:20 AM
        NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T10 = [formatter dateFromString:@"11:50:00"]; // 11:50 AM
        NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T11 = [formatter dateFromString:@"12:20:00"]; // 12:20 PM
        NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T12 = [formatter dateFromString:@"12:50:00"]; // 12:50 PM
        NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T13 = [formatter dateFromString:@"13:20:00"]; // 1:20 PM
        NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T14 = [formatter dateFromString:@"13:50:00"]; // 1:50 PM
        NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T15 = [formatter dateFromString:@"14:20:00"]; // 2:20 PM
        NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T16 = [formatter dateFromString:@"14:50:00"]; // 2:50 PM
        NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T17 = [formatter dateFromString:@"15:20:00"]; // 3:20 PM
        NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T18 = [formatter dateFromString:@"15:50:00"]; // 3:50 PM
        NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T19 = [formatter dateFromString:@"16:20:00"]; // 4:20 PM
        NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T20 = [formatter dateFromString:@"16:50:00"]; // 4:50 PM
        NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T21 = [formatter dateFromString:@"17:20:00"]; // 5:20 PM
        NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T22 = [formatter dateFromString:@"17:50:00"]; // 5:50 PM
        NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T23 = [formatter dateFromString:@"18:20:00"]; // 6:20 PM
        NSDate *bus500_monday_To_Friday_T24 = [formatter dateFromString:@"19:05:00"]; // 7:05 PM

        NSArray *bus500Times = @[bus500_monday_To_Friday_T1,
                                 bus500_monday_To_Friday_T2,
                                 bus500_monday_To_Friday_T3,
                                 bus500_monday_To_Friday_T4,
                                 bus500_monday_To_Friday_T5,
                                 bus500_monday_To_Friday_T6,
                                 bus500_monday_To_Friday_T7,
                                 bus500_monday_To_Friday_T8,
                                 bus500_monday_To_Friday_T9,
                                 bus500_monday_To_Friday_T10,
                                 bus500_monday_To_Friday_T11,
                                 bus500_monday_To_Friday_T12,
                                 bus500_monday_To_Friday_T13,
                                 bus500_monday_To_Friday_T14,
                                 bus500_monday_To_Friday_T15,
                                 bus500_monday_To_Friday_T16,
                                 bus500_monday_To_Friday_T17,
                                 bus500_monday_To_Friday_T18,
                                 bus500_monday_To_Friday_T19,
                                 bus500_monday_To_Friday_T20,
                                 bus500_monday_To_Friday_T21,
                                 bus500_monday_To_Friday_T22,
                                 bus500_monday_To_Friday_T23,
                                 bus500_monday_To_Friday_T24];

        NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:[[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] secondsFromGMT]
                                                 sinceDate:[NSDate date]];;
        NSDate *closestTime500;

        for(NSDate *date in bus500Times)
        {
            if([date timeIntervalSinceDate:currentTime] > 0)
            {
                closestTime500 = date;
                break;
            }
        }

        NSLog(@"Testing first bus time: %@", bus500_monday_To_Friday_T1);
        NSLog(@"Closest time: %@", closestTime500);
```

Comment: Because all of your time values will be earlier than "currentTime".

Comment: (Hint:  NSLog one of your time values.)

Comment: Oh they are all in 2000. How would I make NSDate ignore year, month and day? All I care about is hours, minutes, seconds

Comment: Well, that's one of the reasons I suggested not using NSDate.

Comment: (You shouldn't be mucking with the NSDate timezone like that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

Dump the array of NSDates and keep an array of NSStrings instead.

```
NSArray* busTimes = @[@"06:40:00", @"07:50:00", ...];

NSDateFormatter* fmtr = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[fmtr setFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate nowDate = [NSDate date];
NSString* nowString = [fmtr stringFromDate:nowDate];

NSString* closestTime = nil;

for (NSString* busTime in busTimes) {
    if ([busTime compare:nowString] == NSOrderedDescending ) {
        closestTime = busTime;
        break;
    }
}
```

(Note that I haven't changed the logic in loop, which appears a bit suspicious, depending on whether you assume the data is ordered or not.)

Another way to do it:

```
NSArray* busTimes = @[@"06:40:00", @"07:50:00", ...];
NSDateFormatter* fmtr = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[fmtr setFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSMutableArray* busMinutes = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString* time in busTimes) {
    NSTimeInterval doubleTime = [[fmtr dateFromString:time] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    [busMinutes addObject: [NSNumber numberWithDouble:doubleTime]];
}

NSDate* nowDate = [NSDate date];
NSString* nowString = [fmtr stringFromDate:nowDate];
NSDate* nowDate2 = [fmtr dateFromString:nowString];
NSTimeInterval nowInterval = [nowDate2 timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
double closestTime = 0.0;
double secondsDifference = -99.0;

for (NSNumber* busMinute in busMinutes) {
    double busInterval = [busMinutes doubleValue];
    if (busInterval > nowInterval) {
        closestTime = busInterval;
        secondsDifference = busInterval - nowInterval;
    }
}
```

(Of course, you can't use the above scheme until you can explain what it does.)

Comment: Oh! The compare method in NSString.. I see now. Thanks!! I feel silly

Comment: Me again :P Now I am having trouble getting the seconds between the nowDate and the closestTime. I am not really sure how to go about getting the seconds difference between the next closest bus and the current time.

Comment: Well, you could look at my comment in your previous (nearly identical) question.

Comment: The one about doing arithmetic??

Comment: I know how to do arithmetic with numbers but this is a string?

Comment: It's a string containing 3 numbers.

Comment: Once I can figure out how to turn the local current time into a string I am golden. NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:[[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] secondsFromGMT]
                                                     sinceDate:[NSDate date]];
            NSString *timeString = [df stringFromDate:currentTime];
            NSLog(@"CURRENT TIME: %@", timeString);    How come it doesn't even output anything?   I just want the hours, minutes, and seconds from the currentTime NSDate :S Once I have that I can format

Answer (score 0):

NSDate is stored in GMT.

When you call NSLog it outputs the date in GMT, if your timezone on the device is not GMT then that is not being taken into consideration.

Try logging this

```
NSString *localDate = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:bus500_monday_To_Friday_T1 dateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
```

Comment: I don't want any timezone though? I want the times to be constant in the array.

Comment: I don't know what you mean, you can't use an NSDate and it not have a timezone, it has one whether you like it or not. It has GMT by default, you can't set it to not have one at all. Do you mean you want to store your dates in a timezone independent manner? You effectively are - the timezone comes into play when formatting it for human consumption. You need to do a lot of background research, date handling in general and in iOS is a complex matter.

Comment: Oh ok. How would I set it to my local timezone (I think local means the timezone on iOS device, or is that system?) I have found that the following code is used to change the timezone in the date formatter: formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Europe/Budapest"]    well that is just an example for Europe, but how can I make it take the timezone from the iOS device? I want to use the timezone that the iOS device is currently set to. I am not sure what to replace the string "Europe/Budapest" with.

Comment: There's loads of questions doing that if you search SO